# FBAS to RGB converter available?

Tags: video, composite-video

I am looking for a FBAS to RGB converter, small size, low cost.

**Background:**
Back in the day and until 2008 BMW used to use **RGB** as the video standard in its cars.
Three separate wires, **red green and blue**, would connect all video equipment in the car.
Immediately after that they started using **FBAS** which consists of 3 wires again, but they are denoted as **FBAS+, FBAS- and FBAS Shield**.

**Motive**
I want to upgrade my BMW video/TV module to a newer DVB-T2 module. Unfortunately these newer modules output FBAS, but my head unit and rear screen are still expecting RGB.
This is why I need a mini and low cost FBAS to RGB converter.

A quick search has revealed to me the following:

> "Composite Video (BAS / FBAS):
> The (F)BAS signal is transmitted in an
> unmodulated form and consists of a **brightness and synchronization
> signal, in case of FBAS also of an extra color signal**. The
> transmission of the analog video signal is carried out via a RCA
> (Cinch) or BNC (bayonet) plug connection. "

Source: [K238 Media- / DVI-Converter 7.1.6](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/634220/Ihse-K238-5v.html?page=40)

I am wondering if BMW's FBAS is what they say above.
Also in my search for such converter many sellers sell devices with **Video/AudioL/AudioR (Yellow/White/Red)** as being **Composite**, but this is obviously not what BMW FBAS is!

Can someone more knowledgeable tell me what converter I need to buy (small & cheap) in order to convert the BMW FBAS signal to RGB?

Comment: Not really about retro*computing* mate...

Comment: Straight electronics and potentially where to buy, isn't it? So rather [electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/),but I doubt they will like it.

Comment: No, EE.SE will not take "what to buy and from where" type of questions.

Comment: Why is that “obviously not what BMW FBAS is”? Anyway, probably best to enquire at e.g. [Bimmerforums](https://forums.bimmerforums.com/forum/)